# InputStream->readline blocks execution, how to get partial results from CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future

Read using bufferedStreamReader.readline could block the execution, I want to implement using CompletableFuture and set a timeout, but how can I get partial results of my execution lets say a long read after CompletableFuture has been cancelled as TimeoutException?

Comment: It could only block execution if you're reading from a network, in which case you should be using a read timeout.